# Converting MP3 duration time

Tags: php, math, mp3, duration

I'm using my iTunes library to get data from about 1,100 mp3s and I'm running into a small issue in getting the duration of the library into minutes and seconds.

```
$duration = 1893642;
$minutes = bcmod(($duration / 60), 60);
$seconds = bcmod($duration, 60);
echo $minutes.":".$seconds; //returns 0:42
```

The problem is that this specific MP3 is actually 31:42.  Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$minutes = bcmod(($duration / 60), 60);
```

is taking the minutes modulo 60. Unless your track is over an hour it will always say 0.
You want it to be

```
$minutes = floor($duration / 60);
```

Comment: So you're saying for seconds I should avoid `bcmod()` as well?  I don't understand what `bcmod()` does, someone in another stackoverflow post told me to do it, for most of them it appears to work fine.

Comment: `bcmod` takes the modulus to an arbitrary precision. Basically, `bcmod($a, $b)` means `$a % $b`. Functions beginning with bc- are from the BCMath extension. They allow you to perform arbitrary-precision calculations. Unless your needs call for microsecond resolution (which I doubt), there's not much point in it. Besides, these functions store the numbers as a string, so when you do ordinary division they will be cast to ordinary types and you'll lose the precision.

Comment: This code will only work if what he wants is the following format: "MM:SS" (even it's more than an hour) but if he wants the "HH:MM:SS" this wont work..... So technically Wasim Karani's function is correct. (I don't have a high enough score to downvote this, but it should be down voted.)

Comment: If you want hours just add `$hours = floor($minutes / 60); $minutes %= 60;`. I gave him exactly what he asked for in one line, the other answer is over 15 lines and handles details like string padding. If we really want to be "correct", we shouldn't be doing any of this, since [this functionality is in the standard library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) since PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

**Try** this function

```
function formatTime($secs) {
    $times = array(3600, 60, 1);
    $time = '';
    $tmp = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $tmp = floor($secs / $times[$i]);
        if($tmp < 1) {
            $tmp = '00';
        }
        elseif($tmp < 10) {
            $tmp = '0' . $tmp;
        }
        $time .= $tmp;
        if($i < 2) {
            $time .= ':';
        }
        $secs = $secs % $times[$i];
    }
    return $time;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Not sure if the following function was available when this question was written, but as it's a question I've been asking myself so here goes.*

I used the answer above:

```
$seconds = bcmod($row{'playtime_seconds'}, 60);
$minutes = floor($row{'playtime_seconds'} / 60);
$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
```

Which works for the majority of times, but there is no padding - so you can end up with 20:1 when it should be 20:01 - and it's not to good over an hour - one length comes in at length="1:70:9" - so an alternative is to use the "date" function.

```
<?=date("H:i:s", $duration); ?>
```

which returns **00:31:42** from that number of seconds

Comment: None of this works for the example given.

Comment: 1893642 seconds is 526:00:42. In the first example, the number of hours has to be turned into minutes again and be subtracted from `$minutes`. In the second example the maximum for hours ("H" from "H:i:s") can be 23.

Answer (score 0):

```
$duration_str = sprintf('%s:%02s:%02s',
 floor($duration_int / 3600), // hours
 floor($duration_int / 60) - floor($duration_int / 3600) * 60, // minutes
 $duration_int % 60); // seconds
```

The `*printf` functions provide formatting. In this case the leading zero.

The minutes line is the most complex part, since you have to calculate the hours (duration [s] / 3600 [s/h]), then round down to integer (`floor()`), then multiply with 60 to transform to minutes, then subtract that from the total number of minutes (duration [s] / 60 [s/m]).

If your durations are shorter than an hour, the code is much simpler:

```
$duration_str = sprintf('%s:%02s', floor($duration_int / 60), $duration_int % 60);
```

The result is still correct for a duration greater than 59 minutes, but just not as readable (31560 minutes in the example).